# Segmenting videos during camera capture for higher upload efficiency

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, video-processing, video-capture

I want to develop an Android app that captures a video with the phone's camera, then uploads the video (as a single file) to cloud. And then I want to make it more efficient by segmenting the recorded video into small chunks (say 5 seconds) and upload the chunks to the cloud. And then compare the two approach and show that the second approach is more efficient and provides faster upload according to [this blog](https://netflixtechblog.com/high-quality-video-encoding-at-scale-d159db052746).

Is the chunking approach more efficient? In what ways? And how can I implement this? Shall I wait until the video is finished, then chunk them up, or can we do it in real-time as capturing progresses? Any tips or experience doing this would certainly help.

Comment: @Mick your insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking a video into chunks and performing processing, such are encoding or packaging, in parallel is a very common technique for VOD video at this time.

It allows for faster processing so long as you have the computing resources to tackle tasks in parallel, which many multi core computers and the cloud do have.

It can also allow you to to schedule the processing when your resources are most available, in a period of low load from other jobs for example, or when they are cheapest which can help with cloud computing costs.

Its hard to say if that is more efficient as it depends on what you are measuring - if you added up the total compute instructions or cycles it is quite likely it actually takes more this way, but for the reasons above it is often the preferred approach anyway.

For video transfer or transport, if you were able to send the different chunks on different paths, each of which had a limit that you could fill with that segment, it might indeed provide time savings or efficiency.

However, If your device has a single transmission path, for example it's WiFi IP connection, then the its not clear that segmenting the video would have benefit beyond the 'breaking up' of the video that already happens when you send it packet by packet over an IP network anyway.

If you goal is fast video transmission then it would likely be worth taking a look at some of the specialist protocols which exist for fast and efficient live video transmission. Some of these may be UDP based rather than TCP and if so you may need to check that your target network firewalls and routing rules will support them. SRT would be a good example to look, see like below, bit others exists such as ZiXi which is proprietary:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Reliable_Transport

Focusing on transmission, internet Video streams are actually broken into chunks anyway, because they are delivered over packet networks. The video stream will also be 'chunked' at a higher level also frequently, in addition to encoding and container (e.g. mp4) groupings, to support ABR protocols which segment the video to allow different bitrate renditions be switched between (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365034/334402).

Breaking a video into chunks can also help with playback if the chunks can start playing before the entire video is downloaded - again this is typical of most streamed videos on the internet.

If we ignore any effect of different protocols retry, packet loss etc strategies, and if you have a single transmission 'pipe' of a set capacity, breaking the video into chunks does not make it faster to transfer.

If, however, you have multiple transmission 'pipes' then breaking the video up and sending different parts in parallel across the different pipes may indeed speed it up. It important to remember that, even then, you are limited if the video is a live stream, by the actual live video rate itself - i.e. you can't transfer the video faster than the source is producing it.

Comment: Thanks. So chunking helps with processing on the server, but not necessarily for faster network transfers (upload/download). Is that right?

Comment: @TinaJ, more or less, yes - I've added some more detail to the answer

Comment: Thanks. I'll try chunking up the video and see if it helps...

Comment: Just to be clear - ABR is designed for streaming from a server to a client. If you are uploading a video from a mobile device to a server, for example, you are unlikely to want to use this approach.

Comment: Yes I understand that. One thing I have in mind is if device can support capturing in HEVC, do that and upload it which has half size. If you have any such ideas, I would appreaciate it! :)